# Cloning an macOS encrypted drive for data rescue using GNU ddrescue on Linux

Tags: linux, macos, encryption, data-recovery, ddrescue

I'm using macOS and I have an external hard drive that was force ejected during a copying operation, making it unmountable. There seems to be bad sectors on the drive (which probably was what interfered with the copying operation), so I thought I should clone it using `ddrescue` on my Linux machine (where I have sata ports) and then try to recover the data using `R-studio` for Mac.

After doing some research, it seems like I should run the following `ddrescue` (`GNU ddrescue` that is) commands:

```
ddrescue --no-split /dev/hda1 imagefile logfile
ddrescue --direct --max-retries=3 /dev/hda1 imagefile logfile
```

Now, what might be a problem here is that the hard drive has been encrypted using the native macOS encryption option. Since I'm not that familiar with how this works in detail, I'm not sure whether this would require me to do things differently.

For example, when I plug-in the malfunctioning hard drive under macOS, I'm prompted for my password, meaning I at least can see my folder structure and file names in R-studio (I know I shouldn't be messing around with the hard drive directly, but I did this before I understood why this might be bad). How would this go about if I save the data to an image file on the new hard drive rather than just making a direct, byte for byte, copy on it (in my understanding, replacing `imagefile` in the code above with just the hard drive path would create a direct copy of the original hard drive rather than an image file). Will I be able to unlock the drive somewhere, or will R-studio just se encrypted data? And do I need to use the same file system on the new hard drive in order to decrypt the data?

Further, do I need to rescue all the data that originally was on the drive in order to unlock the encryption, or would I be able to decrypt and rescue parts of it if some of the sectors have broken down all together?

Maybe there are other aspects that I need to take into account as well.

Comment: “I'm prompted for my password, meaning I at least can see my folder structure” Kinda good thing. If you plan to write the image to a new, working hard drive, it seems you might just be able to copy out most of the stuff using the Finder after unlocking the drive. Also, I would check out if after unlocking the drive macOS creates a new device under `/dev/`. If that is the case, also try to clone that one (unlocked) through `ddrescue` on macOS.

Comment: Modern disk encryption (including FileVault) doesn't require the whole drive be perfectly intact to unlock. Can you imagine? That would require reading your *whole* drive every time you unlock it. And you wouldn't have been able to unlock your failing drive. So even if `ddrescue` can't recover every last sector, you should still be able to unlock it.